# Firefox 3.6 does not highlight websites with EV certificates

Tags: firefox, ssl-certificate

When I visit websites that have an EV certificate in FireFox 3.6 - I see this:

[image]

Whereas, I would expect to see this:

[image]

Any idea how I can get FireFox to start displaying EV Certificates correctly? The same websites in IE and Chrome on the same computer display the EV correctly. I can reproduce this on every computer that has FireFox that I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out if you have disabled OCSP (Tools > Options > Advanced > Validation) then EV certificates do not work, because the certificates cannot be validated.

Re-enabling OCSP resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe that a FOSS program has a bug then you are encouraged to visit their bug tracker and see if someone has reported it already, and if not then to report it yourself.

[Mozilla's bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)

Comment: But how do I know that this is a bug, or just some setting I managed to disable?

Comment: Well... it's a matter of following the patterns. This information is too important to let a setting botch it up, and in the event that it *was* a setting to hide the information it would *still* make no sense to show the header along with bogus data. So, a bug either way.